# Retain selected value of the dropdown after page refreshes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to retain selected value of the dropdown after page refreshes on click.

What is happening:

After I select an item from the dropdown the page reloads by itself and the value of the dropdown go to starting position though the value displays on the end of the url.

This is my code:

```
<script>
function refreshPage(passValue){
    window.location="index.php?cat_page=admin_post&sw_cat=sw_catn="+passValue;
}
</script>


<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="inputState">Your health proplem</label>
    <select name="illness_id_cat" class="form-control" onchange="refreshPage(this.value);" >
<?php 
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
    echo "<option value='{$illness_id_cat}'>{$illness_name_cat}</option>";
}
?>
    </select>
</div>
```

This option doesn't work too:

```
<script>
var selectedItem = sessionStorage.getItem("SelectedItem");  
$('#dropdown').val(selectedItem);

$('#dropdown').change(function() { 
    var dropVal = $(this).val();
    sessionStorage.setItem("SelectedItem", dropVal);
});
</script>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="inputState">Your health proplem</label>
    <select name="illness_id_cat" class="form-control" id="dropdown" >
<?php 
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
    echo "<option value='{$illness_id_cat}'>{$illness_name_cat}</option>";
}
?>
    </select>
</div>
```

This I don't know how to implement, what is a "itemname":

```
<script>
var text = localStorage.getItem("itemname");
if(text !== null) {
    $("select option").filter(function() {
        return this.text == text;
    }).attr('selected', true);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think your second version would work if you wrapped the script in a "ready" block. e.g. `$(function() { var selectedItem = sessionStorage.getItem("SelectedItem");  
$('#dropdown').val(selectedItem); });` - this makes sure it doesn't run until _after_ the `<select` has been loaded into the page. Otherwise, it will try to find an element with `id=dropdown` and it won't exist yet - remember that javascript is executed as soon as it's loaded, and that the browser loads each element as soon as it finds it in the HTML document.

Comment: I put the code `<script>
$(function() { var selectedItem = sessionStorage.getItem("SelectedItem"); $('#dropdown').val(selectedItem); });
</script>` to my page but nothing happens, I inserted the id to select too, sorry, in javascript I'm bad

Comment: Do you understand how to debug javascript code using your browser's Developer Tools? Maybe you have an error showing there in the Console. Or you can use the debugger to step through each line of code and see what is happening, and what values the variables have.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Comment: Actually though I forgot, you need to wrap the whole script code in the "ready" block. Otherwise the "change" event will not work either...it will not associate the event with the element because it doesn't exist yet (same reason as for the earlier `$("#dropdown")` selector). So try  `$(function() { var selectedItem = sessionStorage.getItem("SelectedItem");  
$('#dropdown').val(selectedItem);

$('#dropdown').change(function() { 
    var dropVal = $(this).val();
    sessionStorage.setItem("SelectedItem", dropVal);
});});`

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work

Comment: can you be more specific please? It's not really very much of a clue. Do some debugging, check for errors, narrow down the problem, then describe to me the precise behaviour when you try to execute the code.

Comment: P.S. you don't have to use localstorage or sessionstorage for this, you could do it via PHP, that's the more conventional approach.

Comment: Now after refresh the values of the dropdown just go to the starting position again, yes I'll try with the sessions to do that may be

Comment: This my first code worked once though, the first time I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more conventional way to do this would be using PHP, and getting the querystring value you're passing in via the window.location command:

```
<script>
function refreshPage(passValue){
    window.location="index.php?cat_page=admin_post&sw_cat="+passValue;
}
</script>


<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="inputState">Your health problem</label>
    <select name="illness_id_cat" class="form-control" onchange="refreshPage(this.value);" >
<?php 
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
    echo "<option";
    //get the category value from the querystring and check it against the current category value in the loop. If it matches, pre-set the option as selected
    if (isset($_GET["sw_cat"])) {
      if ($_GET["sw_cat"] == $illness_id_cat) echo " selected";
    }
    echo " value='{$illness_id_cat}'>{$illness_name_cat}</option>";

}
?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Here needs one `)` more after `(isset($_GET["sw_cat"])`, thanks, it works!